# I have this error when use SharedPreferences in flutter

Tags: flutter

Hello I am trying to use [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) in flutter but this error appears:

```
NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Future<dynamic>' has no instance method 'setString'.
I/flutter ( 5764): Receiver: Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
```

Here is my code:

```
late SharedPreferences pref;
getPref() async {
  if (pref == null) {
    pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  } else {
    return pref;
  }
}

getPref.setString("");
```

Comment: you need to put key and value in setString("KEY","VALUE");

Answer (score 2):

"getPref" is a Future function, you need to await it before using "setString" to it.

You can try something like this:

```
late SharedPreferences pref;
 getPref() async {
      pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 }

 await getPref();
 pref.setString("MY_KEY", "MY_VALUE");
```

Just by careful with using the "late" keyword, you should check when using "pref" that the value is correct and well set.

Comment: LateInitializationError: Field 'pref' has not been initialized. this error appears

Comment: See my edit, you cannot check the null value on a late non nullable field.

Comment: the previous error appears:  NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Future<dynamic>' has no instance method 'setString'.
I/flutter ( 7022): Receiver: Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'

Comment: Are you calling setString directly on "await getPref()"? If yes, just add a "return pref =..." to the function.

Comment: still the same error

Comment: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Future<dynamic>' has no instance method 'setString'. Receiver: Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'

Comment: On what are you using "setString"?

Comment: to choose a language

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to maybe do it like this:

```
SharedPreferences? pref;

Future<bool> setString(String key, String value) async {
  final p = pref ??= await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return await p.setString(key, value);
}
```